# Please recommend a good Java framework for web development

Tags: java

I am new to Java framework.

I am looking for a good Java framework to help me build a JSP web site.
I googled for Java framework and it returned a few related terms for me:
struts, Cocoon, WebWork.

I have no clue which of them is for beginning learner.
Do I need to download netBean or eclipse to work along with any of these Java Framework?
 I need an auto-complete tool that helps when typing hundreds of lines of code.

Please advise and help.

### Thanks

Edited reason,

I have just found out that netBean has got Struts Java framework, what do you think of it?
 Is it good for beginning learner?

Comment: Struts is a request-based framework, not the component-based. It was one of the earliest attempts to create a web framework for Java but I doubt that many developers would prefer it today. It's just too old.

Answer (score 8):

The [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) makes it easier to build Web applications with Java. I havn't tried it though, but I feel it's "with" the present day web-dev framework ecosystem. It seems inspired by Rails.

Comment: The Play framework looks cool, very Grails / Rails like. But beware that it's not trivial to deploy on a regular appserver or servlet engine.

Answer (score 3):

Very much depends on your concrete needs but I'd invest some time into looking at [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/). It is a really great and flexible framework that promotes best practices.

I admit it will be a bit difficult to understand initially, especially if you're a beginner. But if you're willing to learn it's real fun. For using Spring framework you can use any arbitrary IDE, it really doesn't matter, although personally I prefer the Eclipse IDE, in this special case the [Edition for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliosr).

Comment: Could you recommend me an auto-complete tool for the JAVA framework you mentioned please?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-complete" tool?

Comment: @kwokwai - if you are talking about intellisense, there are many java IDE's - most of which offer intellisense - eclispe, intellij are some popular ones that i am aware of

Comment: Sorry Juri, I mean I need a tool to help me when I am typing codes.

Comment: To complete @kwokwai 's list: Netbeans would be the 3rd IDE in the group. You can just click the link "Edition for Java EE developers" above which will download Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

As [Juri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536622/please-recommend-a-good-java-framework-for-web-development/3536624#3536624) said, Spring is worth looking at. For the specifics of web development, take a look at the [**Spring MVC tutorial**](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).

Answer (score 1):

Spring is pretty good.  Struts is another framework with a pretty easier learning curve IMO.

Answer (score 1):

@kwokwai: I have seen your comment on @Juri post.

Spring IDE would be helpful if you plan to choose Spring for your application.

Answer (score 1):

[Grails](http://grails.org/) is my favorite.
While it's not Java the language, it's Java the platform. It compiles to Java bytecode and runs on any appserver / servlet engine. And integrates well with existing Java code.
Grails is more than just a web framework, it's a complete web application stack. But you can use only the web part if you like.

Grails really brings speed of development known to e.g. Rails to the Java platform.

During development, you can edit your controllers and services, and just hit reload in the browser, no redeploy needed (as you also can in The Play framework).
Tag libraries are really easy to create. And being able to write Groovy code rather than EL in the views (GSP, Grails' variant of JSP) is really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **Apache Wicket**, its very easy, no XML-Configuration-OVerhead. Just have a look a the examples on the [website](http://wicket.apache.org).

Answer (score 1):

Play! Framework. This is by far the easiest one to use. Been a user of Apache Turbine (since 2002), Apache Struts, CakePHP, I finally landed on Play!. You can watch a 10 mins video on http://www.playframework.org/ but here I would like to mention some of my gotchas:

1. Easy, actually too easy to use. Many people's first impression on Play is it makes web dev become fun again on Java
2. Scalable. Because of the stateless model, the only thing you need to do to scale your 5 page hello world web app into a million vists per day busy site is to increase your box and running more instance of your app. You don't need to change one line of code to reach there.
3. Performance. Check [this](http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/) to see how Play! outperforms it's competitors when you use it as a standalone http server
4. Very active community and very good contributors. The questions you post on Play's google group get answered promptly. And you can find many interesting stuff contributed by community at [here](http://www.playframework.org/modules)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). It allows you work with Spring in a very lightweight fashion. In terms of ease of use this seems on par with Play framework or even better (due to tools support). Spring itself is a very established application framework and you are very likely to work with it during your professional career.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm spring user, I would encourage you to look at JBoss Seam. This framework is built on top of other powerful technologies, such as JPA, EJB3 and JSF. You will spent some time learning it of course. And keep in mind, that in order to run its applications, you will need java EE server such as JBoss, not an ordinary servlet container like Tomcat (actually you can run Seam on Tomcat, but you will get into some problems). And java EE hosting costs usually ~two times as much as Tomcat hosting.
Here is the comparison of Spring and Seam:
http://www.andygibson.net/articles/seam_spring_comparison 
Just google `seam vs spring` if you want more details.